# VBA Intellisense only showing after the first period and no levels after typing the first

Tags: vba, excel, macros, intellisense

I'm new to VBA.  I am having trouble with the intellisense but I did not find any answers on here, it seems like people have a different problem than I do.

Whenever I type:
FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6).Value

it works-- this is a valid command, but I am trying to learn and if I do:

Filepath = ActiveWorkbook.

Then the intellisense comes up, and ActiveSheet will be in there. But then if I put another . after Active Sheet, other options won't come up, meaning Cells won't come up as an option.  So it's like there are no other methods/properties after that first Intellisense.

HOWEVER if I were to do something like:

dim mysheet as Worksheet

Set mysheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

and then I do mysheet. the intellisense will come up for that and show me "cells" and other options, but not any levels below that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's because Activesheet could be a chart. By declaring it as a worksheet, you give Intellisense more information to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveSheet` is actually an `Object`, not a `Worksheet` (check the Object Explorer in the VBE with F2). So Intellisense doesn't know it's a `Worksheet`, and doesn't know what members it has. When you explicitly set it to a `Worksheet` variable, it knows the variable's type and can use that to determine the associated members.

[image: Object Explorer]

`ActiveSheet` is an `Object` because `Chart` objects can also have their own sheets, and if a `Chart` sheet is currently activated, it will be the value of `ActiveSheet`. This is the same reason `Workbook.Worksheets` and `Workbook.Sheets` both exist - the former is `Worksheet` objects only, while the latter can also contain `Chart` objects. Consequently, `Sheets(1)` also returns an `Object`, so typing `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).` also won't trigger Intellisense.